# Calling custom Pop up on conditional operator

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a custom dialog (function) on conditional operator but that function is not getting called. Here is my code

Code, where I am calling the function component on meeting a condition,

```
      <Button
        style={{
          marginTop: 8,
          width: "50%",
          background: "#E88A00",
          borderRadius: 20,
          color: "#fff",
          fontFamily: "Poppins !important",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          marginLeft: "10%",
        }}
        autoFocus
        className={classes.goalButton}
        onClick={() => {
          regStatusList.registered === 0 
          ? handleSubmit()
          
          : <Alert message={regStatusList,message} />
        }}
      >
        
        {loading ? (
          <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={24} />
        ) : (
          "Submit"
        )}
      </Button>
```

Alert function component is

```
 function Alert({message) {

  return(
     <div
       style={{
          position: "fixed",
          top: "0",
          right: "0",
          left: "0",
           bottom: "0",
           backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0,0.5)",
       }}
     >
     <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "50%",
        left: "50%",
        background: "white",
        padding:"50px",
      }}
      >
        <h3>{regStatusList?.message}</h3>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            background: "white",
            
          }}
        >
          <Button style={{background: "gray"}}>OK </Button>

      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   )
}
```

How do we call a function component in conditional case like this?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want to get rendered on a Condition must be returned from that function/event listner like:

```
onClick={() => {
          regStatusList.registered === 0 
          ? handleSubmit()
          
          : return <Alert message={regStatusList,message} />
        }}
```